# Max number of elastic IPs that can be attached to single instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-ip

How many elastic IPs (publicly visible) can be attached to single instance?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because ServerFault is not a replacement for the ec2 manual. Please search the amazon manual before asking trivial questions like this.

Comment: The control panel clearly says one per instance.

Comment: I searched the manual and I couldn't find a viable answer. @NathanC it's definitely possible to add more than one. By default it's five max. I didn't find notice about max in general.

Comment: @jayarjo The max is the amount you're allowed to have across all instances without filling out a form for AWS to approve additional IPs. The max is one per instance without a VPC.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in VPC, yes you can. You need to provision extra network cards. From the Documentation;

**Q. Can I assign one or more Elastic IP (EIP) addresses to VPC-based Amazon EC2 instances?**
Yes, however, the EIP addresses will only be reachable from the Internet (not over the VPN connection). Each Elastic IP address must be associated with a unique private IP address on the instance. EIP addresses should only be used on instances in subnets configured to route their traffic directly to the Internet Gateway. EIPs cannot be used on instances in subnets configured to use a NAT instance to access the Internet.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI

Comment: @ceejayoz it's about private IPs.